# Set Raspberry Pi Qt application to full screen mode

Tags: qt, fullscreen, pi

How can I get my QT application to go into full screen mode?

I tried many things from the internet but none of them work. For exmple `QMainWindow::setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint )` and `QMainWindow::showFullScreen( )` (this gives a SIGSEGV).

tia

Comment: where did you create your object ? for example if you create it in main.cpp you need to call `showFullScreen` function instead of show(); which was as default.
like     `MainWindow    w; w.showFullScreen();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Parisa.H.R that worked!